# Dynamic size of even cells (nth cell ) in a table row

Tags: css, cell, css-tables

I have a table with four cells per row. Can I make the second and the fourth cells expand, without changing the width of the others? Can this be done without setting a fixed width to the first and the third cell, because I want to use a class?

```
|cell1|cell2       |cell3|cell4        |
```

another imaginary row

```
|cell1|cell2            |cell3|cell4           |
```

Edit: This is the result I want to achieve. Cell 2 and cell4 should have the same width, and if it is possible, it should be dynamic depending on the window size. Cell 1 and 2 also should have the same width. The 2 examples are not for the same table, they are just to illustrate the idea.

Comment: How do you use class? Why you can't use fixed width?

Answer (score 0):

No, you need each row to be its own table to do that.

```
//row 1
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>

//row2
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use % to make it dynamic with respect to container, like:

```
/*Second and fourth cells*/
div#containerId table td:first-child + td,
div#containerId table td:first-child + td + td + td
{
    width: 30%; 
}
/*First and third cells*/
div#containerId table td:first-child,
div#containerId table td:first-child + td + td
{
    width: 10%; 
}
```